# How to resolve strings indices error in PsychoPy

Tags: python, error-handling, psychopy, experimental-design

I am using PsychoPy tool to run the following experiment

[image]

but I'm getting back the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\PhD experiment\fake experiment (undistracted condition)_lastrun.py", line 383, in <module>
    sentences = filename[['0']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
##### Experiment ended. #####
```

for the sentences _2 object the code is the following one.

```
import requests
import pprint
import pandas as pd 
import random

filename = "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/PhD experiment/B93E1310.xlsx"
sentences = filename[['0']]

random.shuffle(sentences)

if blockcond(currentblock) == 1:
    currentvol = 0
if blockcond(currentblock) == 2:
    currentvol = 1
if blockcond(currentblock) == 3:
   currentvol = 1
```

Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

This are the data I'm working on

```
           init                    sentences pause lastword qstmark                    score       corrAns congruent
1  instructions      this pizza is to hot to           sing       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
2  instructions this morning I ate a bowl of         cereal       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
3  instructions      this pizza is to hot to            eat       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
4  instructions this morning I ate a bowl of          shoes       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
5  instructions      this pizza is to hot to           sing       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
6  instructions this morning I ate a bowl of         cereal       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
7  instructions      this pizza is to hot to            eat       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
8  instructions this morning I ate a bowl of          shoes       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
9  instructions      this pizza is to hot to           sing       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
10 instructions this morning I ate a bowl of         cereal       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
11 instructions      this pizza is to hot to            eat       ? % of corrected responses   right_index         1
12 instructions this morning I ate a bowl of          shoes       ? % of corrected responses middle_finger         0
```

Comment: The error is on the line "sentences = filename[['0']]".  To extract data from an Excel spreadsheet you'll need to use a python library for reading Excel.

Comment: Can you suggest please, which is the corcet one? Thank for your help

Comment: Open the file in Excel, copy and paste the sentences into a plain text file. Then from python:  with open('my_sentence_data.txt') as fid:  sentences = [ln.rstrip() for ln in fid]

Comment: Thanks. So isn't there a different way to access data directly using the excel file?

Comment: yes, there are libraries to read excel from python, but I can't give a useful example without seeing the structure of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok I can edit my post and publish it soon.

Comment: Above the datset I'm using

Comment: So can you suggest a way? Thanks